# how to get kendo mvc grid's destroy command confirmation message events?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

How to get access or modify the Kendo MVC Grid Destroy Command confirmation message OK button event?

Actually, I want to hide/remove all of the custom validation messages once after clicking on "OK" button of Destroy's confirmation box.

I have tried certain things to get the access of delete event. For example:

```
$(".k-button.k-button-icontext.k-grid-delete").live('click', function (e) {
    alert('delete');
});
```

But, this fires after the default click event, and it's firing after both "OK" and "Cancel". So, I'm not able to identify which is the "OK" event and which one is the "Cancel".

Can anyone show me how to do that?

FYI, I'm working on ASP.NET MVC4 with Kendo MVC Grid.

Answer (score 12):

I think you can create a custom command button and call a custom function

```
columns.Command(command => command.Custom("Delete").Click("deleteRow"));
```

disable **DisplayDeleteConfirmation** just in case the confirm window will be displayed twice

```
.Editable(editable => editable
    .Mode(GridEditMode.InCell)
    .DisplayDeleteConfirmation(false))
```

Here is your custom delete function

```
function deleteRow(e) {
    e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete the selected record(s)?")) {
        grid.removeRow($(e.target).closest("tr")); // remove the row
        // custom actions here
    } else {
        // cancel button is clicked
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Peterwcm,its working.But i want to know that how we can add .Datasource action method with that custom template ?

Comment: @pawan sorry, I don't get your question, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: ,i want to know how we can add Kendo Grid .Datasource method for Custom Command like:- Read,Create,Update and Destroy...

Comment: @Pawan If I understand your question correctly, you can bind a RequestEnd event to the datasource. In the javascript function, check the type of the request (create, read, update, destroy), http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource#events-requestEnd